# My Joomla Backend is destoyed - only Text no graphics

Tags: joomla1.5, backend

my Joomla-backend ist destroyed. i can do a log in in a normal way, but then i see only text, no graphics. and also the wohle site is not visible and i can't scoll it. i made a screenshot, please look at it to see what i mean. i have to upgrade my Joomla Version but i cant do it with this broken backend. The current Joomla Version is 1.5.26
So, how can i fix this? I need full acces to my backend. Please help.[image]

Comment: So how did you make it break?

Comment: Some time ago my site was hacked, in the way that a hacker installed a bad php-script in my Joomla-install folder. my provider locked my site and told me to delete this file. After i deleted it the provider gave me acces to my site again, bute then i saw the backend is broken, but the front-end works fine

Comment: Then start over. Delete the Joomla install and reinstall. There is no other (reasonable) way to be certain you have undone everything the hacker did.

Comment: this is the second time that a hacker installed tis bad file. 2 month ago i had the same problem. I deleted the file, the provider gave me access and everything was fine. but this time - the same procedure - and the backend is broken. So... is there no other way than to reinstall joomla?

Comment: If you have to ask, then no, there is no other way. Also, reinstalling is the only sure way. I would recommend that you figure out what you're doing wrong that you keep getting infected though.

Answer (score 0):

This is why we should not use older version of joomla. 
you must install newer version of joomla
It is more reliable and secure. 
[Here is the step by step migration process](https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_1.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration)